# How to add a footer widget column in StoreFront Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, storefront

I would like to add a 5th column in footer and fill it from widget area. I am not sure what is needed here. I did in my functions.php in my child theme

```
add_filter( 'storefront_footer_widget_columns', 'MyFooterColumns' );
function MyFooterColumns( $columns ) {
 return 5;
}
```

but nothing happens
How shall I add another column?

Answer (score 1):

it's working. Your code is correct.
If you go to admin `wp-admin/widgets.php`, u will see the the fifth column.